# Logarithmic HighCharts X-Axis

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I currently have a HighCharts graph, with the x-axis range 300 to 1 (1 being the highest rank, and 300 to be the lowest).

The problem is that if the data points range from 200 to 1, the change from 10 to 1 does not look significant.

Is there anyway to modify a HighCharts graph to stretch out the changes that are closer to the highest value (1) so that the jump in values are more significant?

Comment: Perhaps use a dynamic min/max such that if you only have points from 1 to 200 your max is 200?

Comment: Yes the chart auto-adjusts right now, but if there are points plotted from 200 to 1, the change from the (more significant) values of 20 to 1 will not look as significant..

Comment: If you could create demo with that it would be helpful. For me both standard and logarithmic axes works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/981/

Comment: A lot more info is required.  First question: "the change from 10 to 1 does not look significant" Well...is it significant? And why a logarithmic axis? Sounds like "are we measuring the right thing, the right way?" is a relevant question as well.